# Can I include Pyomo.dae into a larger network problem

Tags: pyomo

Basically, I want to optimize a process that includes a heater, a flash unit and a PFR. I've defined constraints for all the units, but don't quite understand how to incorporate the PFR dae model into the overall process model and solve for them together.

I would appreciate some explanation of the architecture of pyomo and how it can combine these models.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have those models, format a mathematical model first and define the decision variables and build your pyomo model.